# Как правильно прописать relations к другой бд?

Tags: yii, activerecord, relation

У меня есть 2 БД: `bd` и `bd2`. В `bd2` есть таблица `schools1` с моделью `schools1`, в `bd` есть таблица `mon_st_result` c моделью `STResult`. В обеих моделях есть функции `public function getDbConnection()`.

Для модели `schools1` прописываю `relations`:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
            'area' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Areas', array('AreaCode' => 'AreaCodeFK')), 
            'stresult' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'STResult', array('ResultEduOrg' => 'SchoolCode'))//связь с таблицей из БД bd
    );
}
```

Первая связь обращается к таблице из этой же БД `bd2`, там все нормально. А вот связь `stresult` не работает (там идет обращение из другой БД `bd`).

Yii выдаёт ошибку:

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Мое Название bd2.mon_st_result' doesn't exist.//должна быть связь с таблицей из БД bd, а не bd2

Как правильно сделать связь для таблицы из другой БД?

Comment: Попробуйте возвращать имена таблиц в `tableName()` c указанием имен БД. Но это очень плохая практика, все должно быть внутри одной БД.

Comment: Да, так стало работать, спасибо.